# Area 51 on iOS app

Tags: feature-request, area-51, android-app, ios-app

Can we have a way to access Area 51 on the iOS and android app?

More sites would flourish due to more traffic.

Comment: @AndrewT. very true. I'm here for ~5 years, never seen even a single status-deferred becoming status-completed. By all means, it's just a different wording for status-rejected.

Comment: @AndrewT. Yep, it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Mutantoe If you agree it's a dupe, please click the 'Yes, this solved my problem' box!

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Ironically, this doesn't appear on the mobile app. I'll fix it shortly.

Comment: Might be worth another feature-request... :)