# Allow OP to mark own question as a dupe when there is a pending close vote (binding vote)

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, ios-app

When asking [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257277/290073) question, it was  flagged as a duplicate. However, I was unable to accept this duplicate, I couldn't even see that it had been flagged.

Can we have a way to do this in the app?

Note: This may apply to Android as well.

Comment: This is a rather new feature, guess it will take some time, if at all, until it's available through the API. (which is first step towards having it in the apps) - anyway, totally not a bug.